Multi-screen no longer supported in VM with some kernel versions
Recently (end of July 2024) my Ubuntu 22 LTS VM no longer has correct support for multiple screens.
When using a VM in full-screen mode VMware has a "Cycle multiple monitors" button.
Clicking this once will expand the VM to cover both (physical screens); clicking again should return to a single screen.
There are multiple ways this fails now, but it never works correctly
I am using VMware Workstation Player. This happens for both version 15 and 17.
This also happens with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20, 22 or 24 (LTS each) as well as Debian 12.
This also happens on different hardware.
I am able to isolate this to different kernel versions on fresh VMs.
In all cases I used "Gnome on X.org" / "Ubuntu on X.org".
Curiously the behaviour is exactly the opposite for Wayland.



uname -nrv
X11
Wayland




ubuntu-22-test 5.15.0-113-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 10 08:16:17 UTC 2024
good
bad


ubuntu-22-test 5.15.0-116-generic #126-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 1 10:14:24 UTC 2024
bad
good


debian12 6.1.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.85-1 (2024-04-11)
good
bad


debian12 6.1.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03)
bad
good



Obviously a kernel downgrade would help, but that is not a real solution.
Ideally an answer would allow me to resolve this issue, but any information that will help me understand this would be appreciated.

it doens't look like a kernel problem to me , but more like an hypervisor problem.

Known Issues The multi-monitor feature might not work correctly in
specific topologies
In specific situations, based on different hardware and topologies,
the multi-monitor feature does not work as expected. You might see
issues like reverting the topology to a single screen, or not cycling
through monitors.
Workaround: None.

source: VMware Workstation 17.5.2 Pro Release Notes
